# What's wrong with this rails syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Well, I hate using SO as just a syntax checker, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why I get thi error

```
where line #8 raised:
unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

Here is the offending code:

```
5:   <%= f.input :allele2 %>
6:   <%= f.input :run_date %>
7: 
8:   <%=f.association :gmarkers, :collection => Gmarker.all(:order => 'marker'), :prompt => "Choose a Marker", :label => "Marker" %>
9:
```

I'm using the SimpleForm gem, and am not too familiar with it yet (obviously!)

tia,
--rick

Comment: You would have to post the full code for the form (e.g. starting with <%= simple_form_for() .. to be sure, but "expecting keyword_end" means that you're missing an "end" to go with a do block - in this case, probably missing <% end %> at the bottom of your form generating code.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `<% end %>` after your last line there, line 8.